# Blogger Templates - Issue with Anoymous avatar

Tags: javascript, css, blogger

I have a blog created with Blogger since few years. I noticed something strange. When an anonymous visitor go on my website, an image cannot be found in comment widget:

[image]

I try to create a new blog with exactly same theme and same parameters and all working fine:

[image]

What's wrong? I've already checked CSS, JS, ... and I can't what the differences between these two blogs.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can ask this question at https://support.google.com/blogger/ . Here you would find people who are experts at blogger stuff. Plus can you add both the blog links, for us to see.

Comment: This issue resolved itself today. I think it was a bug from Blogger.